# Live tiles stopped working

Tags: settings, sync, 8.0

I have myself, my photos, and a friend pinned to my start.  The tiles used to rotate photos, but I forgot my wallet pin, did a reset, and now those tiles don't update (my 'weather view' app tile does update). The photos app has nothing, even though my accounts and albums are there, and myself and my friend just show our static facebook photo.

Answer (score 2):

When you reseted it might have the apps' background tasks turned off which will prevent the live tiles from working.

To fix this:

- Go to settings
- slide left to get to "Applications"
- Press "Background Tasks"
- (This page will list all the apps that can work with live tiles)
- (Under each of the apps you want to work on live tiles, they should each have "On" highlighted under them)
- If your app says "Off", Press it.
- (This should take you to a new page with a button)
- Press the "Turn On" button.
- Exit out of everything to your tiles.
- (The live tile for that app should work now)

In your photos app (if not fixed)

- Open photos app
- Press the 3 dots on the bar at the bottom
- Press shuffle background
  That should fix the photos problem

### If none of this worked

- Something must have gone wrong during the reset and you should reset your phone again or call support.

### Notes

- If you haven't used an app for two weeks, the live tile will not work and you will have to turn it on.